# Is it possible to login a website with different user at the same time in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, website, browser-tabs

**For example:**

I want to access `forexample.com` in one tab and login as `email1@gmail.com` then i open up another tab type the same website (forexample.com) and login as `email2@gmail.com` and so on upto 5 to 6 user. I know that i can't. But is there any to way to do this? Or is there any extension for this functionality?. I came up with a solution in which you can access by open up a chrome general and incognito mode. But for me that's not enough. 
please note i am using chrome browser.

Comment: Use a different browser that allows you to have multiple profiles. Even in that case it still would depend on how `forexample.com` implements their stuff.

Comment: i kinda like one browser which is chrome.but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome settings, in the section "People", you can choose "Browse as guest", or add new persons. You'll get a separate window where you can login, without incognito mode.

Guest mode won't keep cookies, I think, but other people (I'd call it identities) certainly will.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the incognito mode on Chrome.

Open the website in the existing new window, and log in, and by opening the website on incognito mode, you can log in again, **without** having to log out.

Comment: I think i can't login as 2-user , in facebook for example, in two different incognito mode window at the same time and i also mention in question that i don't want the incognito mode.but thanks for the effort of answering. i accepted the @Demosthenes because it solved my problem.

Comment: Not a problem. :)